# ASP.NET Core request timeout not triggering

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-8

I can't get the timeout to automatically trigger in the ASP.NET Core 8.0 Preview.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/timeouts?view=aspnetcore-8.0

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddRequestTimeouts();

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseRequestTimeouts();

app.MapGet("/", async (HttpContext context) =>
    {
        try
        {
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), context.RequestAborted);
        }
        catch (TaskCanceledException)
        {
            return Results.Content("Timeout!", "text/plain");
        }

        return Results.Content("No timeout.", "text/plain");
    })
    .WithRequestTimeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

app.Run();
```

**Expected output:** Trigger a timeout after 1 second

**Actual output:** Returns success after 10 seconds

Comment: There is no problem with this, it triggers a timeout. What was your response?

Comment: @Chen I am experiencing "Success after 10 seconds". I expect it to trigger a timeout after 1 second. I updated my question with expected and actual output.

Comment: No Repro with this exact code. I always get `Timeout!`. I tried this with both Preview 4 and Preview 5. The article isn't specific to ASP.NET Core 8 anyway. How did you test this?

Comment: Are you sure you aren't looking at cached output from a previous attempt? Try changing `Results.Content("Timeout!", "text/plain");` to `Results.Content("Timeout!", "text/plain", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, 500);` to ensure the browser doesn't cache the output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you run your application with a debugger attached the request timeout check is skipped.

`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Timeouts.RequestTimeoutsMiddleware` that is added with `UseRequestTimeouts` contains the following code:

```
internal sealed class RequestTimeoutsMiddleware
{
    public Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        if (Debugger.IsAttached)
        {
            return _next(context);
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/v8.0.0-preview.5.23302.2/src/Http/Http/src/Timeouts/RequestTimeoutsMiddleware.cs#L31

Answer (score 2):

I believe using "Start Without Debugging" will help.